# format function changes unicode characters

Tags: r, unicode

I'm trying to use the `format` function, but it changes unicode charactes. You can see this happening in the example below:

```
> cat(format('\u2265', width=20))
=
```

It should print this character:

```
> cat('\u2265')
[1] ≥
```

Any ideas why this happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `encodeString` function doesn't have the same issue, and has the same functionality.